# When I swipe to remove the list item disappears for a split second then comes back

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code, when I swipe the list item goes away but then comes right back??

The intention is to have the user swipe. the list item is then not only removed visually but from my database via a call to a PHP script. Everything works great but the removed list item comes right back. Please help I am going crazy here! I attempted to remove all personal info, if you guys need more information please let me know.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">


<style>
/* Left transition */

li.left {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 250ms ease;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 250ms ease;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -o-transition: -o-transform 250ms ease;
    -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: transform 250ms ease;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}
/* Right transition */
li.right {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 250ms ease;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 250ms ease;
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    -o-transition: -o-transform 250ms ease;
    -o-transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 250ms ease;
    transform: translateX(100%);
}
/* Border bottom for the previous button during the transition*/
li.left a.ui-btn, li.right a.ui-btn {
    border-top-width: 0;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 1px;
}
li a.ui-btn.border-bottom {
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
/* Hide the delete button on touch devices */
ul.touch li.ui-li-has-alt a.delete {
    display: none;
}
ul.touch li.ui-li-has-alt a.ui-btn {
    margin-right: 0;
}
/* Styling for the popup */
#confirm p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: inherit;
    margin-bottom: .75em;
}
</style>
<script>


</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="demo-page" data-title="hem" data-url="demo-page">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
   <center> <br><font size="+3">hqaw</font></center><br>
    <a href="#demo-intro" data-rel="back" data-icon="carat-l" data-iconpos="notext">Back</a> <a href="#" onClick="window.location.reload()" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext">Refresh</a> </div>
  <!-- /header -->
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <ul id="list" class="touch" data-role="listview" data-icon="false" data-split-icon="delete">
      <li data-role="list-divider">
        <font size="+2">Pick Ups</font>
      </li>


                                <li id='25'><a href='#popup_25' data-rel='popup'>
                                <h2 class='Name'>11151511</h2>
                                <p>07.00 AM</p>
                                <p><strong>sosaville</strong></p>
                                <p>sammyc</p>
                                </a></li>     
      <li data-role="list-divider">
        <font size="+2">Drop Offs </font>
      </li>

      <br><center><table width='80%'><tr><td><p><h2>No body knows.</h2></p></td></tr></table></center>      
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /content -->

  <div data-role="footer">
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="main.php" data-ajax="false"><font size="+2">Main Menu</font></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /navbar --> 
  </div>
  <!-- /footer --> 
 <div id='popUps'>
  <div id ="popup_25" class="ui-content" data-role="popup" data-theme="a">
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
    11151511<br><br><a href='https://maps.google.com/?q=samon, dallas, TX, USA'>12005 Dallas Parkway, dallas, TX, USA</a>
<br><br><Br><a href='tel:212-121-2121'>212-121-2121</a><br>Wants to be picked up at: 07.00 AM<br></div>  </div>
  <div id="confirm" class="ui-content" data-role="popup" data-theme="a">
    <p id="question">Are you sure you want to add:</p>
    <div class="ui-grid-a">
      <div class="ui-block-a"> <a id="yes" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-mini ui-btn-a" data-rel="back">Yes</a> </div>
      <div class="ui-block-b"> <a id="cancel" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-mini ui-btn-a" data-rel="back">Cancel</a> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /popup --> 
</div>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.7.4/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    ///#########################PRIVATE
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);


var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('update_tor');
  //dbRef.on('value', fRefresh());


var isInitialValue = true;
dbRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  if (isInitialValue) {
    isInitialValue = false;
  }
  else {


       $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "waitingData.php",
      success: function(data){
          $('#list').empty().append(data); 

            },

      complete: function() {

           $('#list').listview('refresh');
          onPageLoad();

        }
    });


      $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "waitingData.php?popUps=1",
      success: function(data){
          $('#popUps').empty().append(data); 
          $('#popUps').trigger("create");
            }
      });
  }
});

  $( document ).on( "pagecreate", "#demo-page", function() {
    // Swipe to remove list item
    $( document ).on( "swipeleft swiperight", "#list li", function( event ) {
        var listitem = $( this ),
            // These are the classnames used for the CSS transition
            dir = event.type === "swipeleft" ? "left" : "right",
            // Check if the browser supports the transform (3D) CSS transition
            transition = $.support.cssTransform3d ? dir : false;
            confirmAndDelete( listitem, transition );
    });




    // If it's not a touch device...
    if ( ! $.mobile.support.touch ) {
        // Remove the class that is used to hide the delete button on touch devices
        $( "#list" ).removeClass( "touch" );
        // Click delete split-button to remove list item
        $( ".delete" ).on( "click", function() {
            var listitem = $( this ).parent( "li" );
            confirmAndDelete( listitem );
        });
    }
    function confirmAndDelete( listitem, transition ) {

        if(!listitem.attr("id")){
            return false;
        }

        // Highlight the list item that will be removed
        listitem.children( ".ui-btn" ).addClass( "ui-btn-active" );
        // Inject topic in confirmation popup after removing any previous injected topics
        $( "#confirm .Name" ).remove();
        listitem.find( ".Name" ).clone().insertAfter( "#question" );
        // Show the confirmation popup
        $( "#confirm" ).popup( "open" );
        // Proceed when the user confirms
        $( "#confirm #yes" ).on( "click", function() {
            // Remove with a transition


            if ( transition ) {
                listitem
                    // Add the class for the transition direction
                    .addClass( transition )
                    // When the transition is done...
                    .on( "webkitTransitionEnd transitionend otransitionend", function() {
                        // ...the list item will be removed

    var TripID = listitem.attr("id");


                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "response.php",
                    cache: false,
                    data: "DriverID=101&TripID="+TripID,
                    success:  listitem.remove(),
                    error: onError
                });

    // update firebase here
    var updates = {};
  updates['/update_tor/'] = Date.now();
  return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);

                        // ...the list will be refreshed and the temporary class for border styling removed
                        $( "#list" ).listview( "refresh" ).find( ".border-bottom" ).removeClass( "border-bottom" );
                        $( "#list" ).listview( "refresh" );
                    })
                    // During the transition the previous button gets bottom border
                    .prev( "li" ).children( "a" ).addClass( "border-bottom" )
                    // Remove the highlight
                    .end().end().children( ".ui-btn" ).removeClass( "ui-btn-active" );
            }
            // If it's not a touch device or the CSS transition isn't supported just remove the list item and refresh the list

            //
            else {
                listitem.remove();
                $( "#list" ).listview( "refresh" );
            }
            //




        });
        // Remove active state and unbind when the cancel button is clicked
        $( "#confirm #cancel" ).on( "click", function() {
            listitem.removeClass( "ui-btn-active" );
            $( "#confirm #yes" ).off();
        });
    }



});

function onError(data, status)
        {
            alert(error);
           data = $.trim(data);
            $("#notification").text(data)
        } 

  </script>
      <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    onPageLoad();
     });


</script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current snippet :-

> Uncaught ReferenceError: onPageLoad is not defined
>       at HTMLDocument. (index.html:286)

Comment: Yes sorry please remove this part of the code:

    $(document).ready(function(){
        onPageLoad();
     });